# Getting the error following error when using plotly. AttributeError: module 'plotly.graph_objects' has no attribute 'figure'

Tags: python, plotly

Below is my code from Jupyter Notebook.

```
import chart_studio.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
data = dict(type='choropleth',
            locations=['CA', 'NY', 'AZ'],
            locationmode='USA-states',
           colorscale='ylorbr',
           text=['text1','text2','text3'],
           z=[1.0, 2.0, 3.0],
           colorbar={'title':'ColorbarTitle'})
#text- which hovers over all the locations
layout=dict(geo={'scope':'usa'})
choromap = go.figure(data=[data], layout=layout)
```

I have already done the below steps:
pip install chart-studio
pip install ipywidgets

Plotly version used: 4.7.1

Below is the error trace:
[image: AttributeError: module 'plotly.graph_objects' has no attribute 'figure']

The nearest I have found is the below links:
https://community.plotly.com/t/attributeerror-module-plotly-graph-objs-has-no-attribute-figurewidget-after-upgrading-to-plotly-4-7/39034

And

also tried out the below:
from plotly import graph_objects as go

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: It's `go.Figure()` with capital "F".